# Is there a way to use both test keys localhost and live keys remote with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a project were I set up keys as such.

Live keys

```
  functions:config:set stripe.secret="sk_live_..." stripe.publishable="pk_live_..."
```

Test keys

```
 functions:config:set stripe.secret="sk_test_..." stripe.publishable="pk_test_..."
```

The application is in its beta stage but live. So there's a lot more changes still done in code.
So I want to avoid setting the keys each time I want to test out some new feature on localhost.

Is there a way to configure firebase functions, to correspond to different Environments?

When on localhost, it should validate with test keys and with on remote live keys?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a special per-environment configuration.  What you can do instead is use the unique id of the project to determine which settings it should apply.  Functions can read the deployed project id out of the [process environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#reserved_keys_key_validation) with `GCP_PROJECT`

```
const project_id = process.env.GCP_PROJECT
```

The values you should use during development is a matter of opinion - do whatever suits you the best.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make a `.runtimeconfig.json` file in your `functions` directory, which the emulators will read.

For example, first set your local values with `firebase functions config:set stripe.secret="sk_test_...",

Then, run `firebase functions config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`

When that file is present, from my experience, your firebase emulators will read from that, and you won't keep overwriting production config variables.

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional